# when i use pm2 to manager my node cluster,how can i merge different processes`s logs into one file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

e.g. process A has two log file ,one is err,the other is out,process B has the same situation,now,how can i merge the two err file into one err file,and the out file?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#configuring-logs), you can either pass `--merge-logs` as a command line argument, or set `merge-logs` to `true` in you config json.